# How to Attach JSON to Existing JSON and Use it in Pug in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have two functions like below but whenever I am doing  `r.replies = JSON.stringify(repliesArr);` without JSON.Stringify, it is coming as [Object].

[image]

```
function getContentReplies(author, permlink) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getReply(author, permlink, function (err, resp) {
      if(err) reject(resp)
        resp.map(r => {
          r.body = marked(r.body)
          if(r.children > 0)
            return getContentReplies(r.author, r.permlink)
                .then(c => {
                  let repliesArr = [];
                  for (var a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
                      let i = {
                      author: c[a].author,
                      category: c[a].category,
                      permlink: c[a].permlink,
                      title: c[a].title,
                      body: c[a].body
                    }
                    repliesArr.push(i);
                  }

                  r.replies = JSON.stringify(repliesArr);
                  return r;
                })
          else
            return r
        })
      resolve(resp);
    })
  })
}

async function getComments (username, permlink) {
  console.log('-------------')
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getReply(username, permlink, function (err, resp) {
      if (err) console.log(err)
      let promises = resp.map(r => {
        r.body = marked(r.body)
        if(r.children > 0)
          return getContentReplies(r.author, r.permlink)
              .then(c => {
                let repliesArr = [];
                for (var a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
                    let i = {
                    author: c[a].author,
                    category: c[a].category,
                    permlink: c[a].permlink,
                    title: c[a].title,
                    body: marked(c[a].body)
                  }
                  repliesArr.push(i);
                }

                r.replies = JSON.stringify(repliesArr);
                return r;
              })
        else
          return r
      })
      Promise.all(promises)
        .then(results => {
          console.log(results);
          return results;
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
          reject(e);
        })
      resolve(resp);
    })
  })
}
```

Since I have to use replies in Pug when I do JSON.parse(replies) it gives an error as `Unexpected end of JSON input`

EDIT: Replies Object

[image]

Comment: if you are trying to parse a `json` object instead of a `json string` in `JSON.parse(myjsonobj)` it will always give you an error. Can you check if the `replies` obj is a `json string` and not an `Json object`.

Comment: @vikscool I am constructing the JSON object out here `{
                      author: c[a].author,
                      category: c[a].category,
                      permlink: c[a].permlink,
                      title: c[a].title,
                      body: c[a].body
                    }` and adding it to the array

Comment: the only reason for the `replies` object to have `[Object]` instead of the jsonString is that a `string` proptotype 'toString()' is being called on the `repliesAr object` which will return the `[Object]`. So, can you please check if the stringifying of `repliesAr` object is needed and if not you can avoid it and just assign the array to the the `r.replies` object.

Comment: That's what I am doing, when I am not stringifying the object it shows as `[Object]` which I do not want

Comment: can you post the json of `replies` object which you are trying to parse on `JSON.parse(replies)` and are you having the `[Object]` instead of jsonObject in javascript side or on when you send it to `pug.js` side.

Comment: @vikscool I have added the replies object screenshot to the original question , I guess I am having the JSON object.